# How to start an animation when a child view controller's view actually appears?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am building a tutorial that uses custom subclasses of UIViewController to supply views for the tutorial. I would like to have a subview with instructions appear and then slowly fade out. I am trying to do it this way: a wrapper page controller class, custom UIViewController classes added as child view controllers, and an animation added to the custom UIViewController class's view.

Here is an example of how I add a child view controller to a tutorial page view:

```
    else if(index==2)

{

    FollowTutorViewController *next1 = [[FollowTutorViewController alloc] init];
    next1.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    next1.typeDisplay = 1;
    next1.index = index;
    [page addChildViewController:next1];
    next1.view.frame = page.view.frame;
    [page.view addSubview:next1.view];
}
```

And here is an example of how I do the animation within the subclassed UIViewController:

```
- (void)messageTutorial
{

    CGFloat height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
    CGFloat width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;

    UILabel *directionsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(width/2, height/2, 100, 100)];
    directionsLabel.backgroundColor = ORANGE_COLOR;
    directionsLabel.textColor = BACKGROUND_COLOR;
    directionsLabel.text = @"Follower pages show who you're following and who's following you\n\nYou can also see a list of most-controversial posters when you look for New People \n\nBuzz and Judge to gain followers";
    directionsLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:SMALL_FONT_SIZE];

    [directionsLabel setLineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [directionsLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(width*.8 , 200000.0f);
    CGSize size = [directionsLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:SMALL_FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint];


    directionsLabel.alpha = .8;
    CGRect f = directionsLabel.frame;
    f.size = size;
    directionsLabel.frame = f;
    directionsLabel.center = self.view.center;
    [self.tableView addSubview:directionsLabel];


     [UIView animateWithDuration:15 animations:^{
     directionsLabel.alpha = 0;

     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
     [directionsLabel removeFromSuperview];

     }]; 
}
```

I would like to make the label disappear slowly starting when the user sees that view, but now when I run this code, regardless of where I call it, the view is gone by the time the user looks at the page. I have tried running this code in viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, viewDidLayoutSubviews of the child custom UIViewController. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Could you post the entire method containing that animation?

Comment: Are you seeing FollowTutorViewController's view at all? Where are you making that controller, storyboard, or xib? Your code works fine for me in viewDidAppear.

Comment: @rdelmar Yes I'm seeing FollowTutorViewController's view just as it should be. And if I comment out the animation, I do see directionsLabel, just as I should. But if I animate, I think it somehow gets initialized and disappears before I can even see it. If I put a log inside the animation, I do see that print out.

Comment: So your theory is that the animation starts and ends too soon? Well, you are allowed to specify a delay for the start time of an animation. So why not try that? If you do that, does it solve the problem?

Comment: If I put in the delay, it works. But this is inexact, as I have to guess the right time and it could vary device-to-device.

Comment: I still can't duplicate your problem. I copied and pasted the code into a UIViewController subclass, with a table view, and it worked fine. I called messageTutorial from viewDidAppear.

Comment: @rdelmar That's interesting. I already tried resetting my build settings, but I will try it again.

Comment: @SunnysideProductions Sorry, I wasn't paying attention closely enough - so it sounds like the _real_ problem here is that there is unexpected delay in when your new view appears? But `addSubview` is more or less immediate. So why is there this delay? Are you mistakenly calling that code in a background thread? Is there a surrounding animation you have not told us about? Show the full code used to replace one view with another (or whatever).

Comment: If there is an animation, then all you have to do is start the next animation in its completion handler - right?